# NodeJS - how to pass async data from a model with module.exports?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rethinkdb

I'm trying to get data from a document in RethinkDB in NodeJS and pass the result into a variable I wish to use in a template file, but it is always `undefined` when I try to print the `data` variable like `#{data}` (I'm using pug/jade) because it's an asynch call (i think).

```
'use strict';

var r = require('rethinkdb');

module.exports = function IndexModel() {
    data: {
        r.connect({host: '127.0.0.1', port: 28015}, function(err, conn) {
            r.db('mydb').table('mytable').run(conn).then(function(cursor) {
                cursor.toArray(function(err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    return JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
                });
            });
        });
    }
};
```

I figured it must be because nodejs want it to be an object, so I tried to parse it like `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))` but that throws the same error.

When I do `console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))` it prints this **after** the error.

```
[
  {
    "id": "307ad5e9-a0db-461b-a564-081d73f9b34f",
    "title": "hello"
  }
]
```

This is the exact error if its needed:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at eval (eval at wrap (C:\Users\Me\Project\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:248:32)
    at eval (eval at wrap (C:\Users\Me\Project\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:379:4)
    at template (eval at wrap (C:\Users\Me\Project\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:389:211)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Users\Me\Project\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:427:38)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Users\Me\Project\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:417:21)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (C:\Users\Me\Project\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:464:11)
    at C:\Users\Me\Project\node_modules\engine-munger\index.js:133:22
    at C:\Users\Me\Project\node_modules\engine-munger\index.js:154:17
    at C:\Users\Me\Project\node_modules\engine-munger\index.js:87:21
    at C:\Users\Me\Project\node_modules\engine-munger\index.js:189:13
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
```

Any idea how I can solve this everlasting problem? Thanks!

**Edit:**

It appears that I can not return anything from the `data` variable inside any rethinkdb connection or promise, it has to be outside of it to get detected.

Comment: The code probably doesn’t do what you want it to do at all. The function doesn’t rerun anything. What is the purpose of `data`? Also, converting a value to JSON just to parse it again is as if you where conveying a number to a string and back (`parseInt('' + 42, 10)`): it’s completely useless, you better not stringify the value in the first place (`42`).

Comment: @FelixKling The purpose of `data` is to hold an object so I can loop it in my template file with `each`. I got the stringify part from the official RethinkDB docs, so I just assumed that was the way to do it because everything else failed as well.

Comment: In the code in your question, `data:` is a [**label**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), not a property. You are missing `{...}` around `data:` to make it a property. You might want to read [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `async/await` might work for you

> mymodule.js

```
module.exports = async function IndexModel() {
        let conn = await r.connect({host: '127.0.0.1', port: 28015});
        let cursor = await r.db('mydb').table('mytable').run(conn)
        try {
            let arr = await cursor.toArray();
            return arr
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }
}
```

> main.js

```
let indexModel = require('mymodule.js');

indexModel().then(result => {
    console.log(result.length)
})
```

Comment: You can return `{data: result}` if you like

Comment: I tried as you suggested with returning `{data: result}` and it gives me this error: https://pastebin.com/NhAZcapS Furthermore it prints `1` as the length in console.

Comment: It appers to somewhat "work" when I pass the result to the render function instead of parsing the result. However the deprecation warning still stands, and whats weirder is that it prints like 50 items (there's only 1) and I can not access any of the key values, they are all empty. if I print the result to console it says `{ mytable: '[\n  {\n    "id": "307ad5e9-a0db-461b-a564-081d73f9b34f",\n    "title": "hello"\n  }\n]',
  _locals: { _csrf: 'FpoZxyUSuMK5Sl09juoXWwEFiEoJXiZsLqiYM=' } }` so this is confusing.

Comment: I have edited my answer - this happens when your data is already an object, and your trying to call `JSON.parse` on it. Try removing it and see if that helps. Also, as was mentioned before, There's no need to call `JSON.stringify` on the results from the database if you're planning on parsing them again. just return `arr` and logging it and it should work.

Comment: Didn't see your latest comment. Thanks! It works like a charm now. I'm so happy this problem finally got solved after days of trying to figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your code with this one:

```js
const r = require('rethinkdb');

module.exports = function indexModel() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {
      host: '127.0.0.1', 
      port: 28015
    };
  
    r.connect(params, (err, conn) => {
      // check availability
      if (error) return reject(error);
    
      r.db('mydb')
       .table('mytable')
       .run(conn)
       .then(cursor => {
          cursor.toArray((error, result) => {
            if (error) return reject(error);
            
            const data = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
            return resolve({
              data: data
            });
          });
        });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but nothing is bound to the `data` variable, which I need to be able to loop through the object in my template file. How would that be accomplished using this method?

Comment: @P.Nick check it now. The function `indexModel` returns a Promise which returns `data` parameter if all is success

Comment: thanks, but it is still giving me `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Are you sure you have any data inside a DB? if you don't, insert something and try it again

Comment: Yes there is data, as I said in the post I can console.log the result and it prints the json correctly. As a side note, I can't seem to return anything with the `data` variable inside any rethinkdb connection or promise, not even with raw data.

Comment: I think that a problem is in your template engine. Can you tell me which one do you use?

Comment: Pug doesn't allow you to use data from callbacks or Promises. So, you should use it in the next way: `indexModel().then(object => runTemplate(object))`